# Replace y-Axis labels in chartist.js

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I have no idea how to replace the y-Axis label in chartist! I have not found anything in the [Chartist.js - API Documentation](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html). I need to **replace 0 by X, 2 by B and 1 by A**. Ideas would be great!

```
var data = {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
    series: [
        [2,2,1,0,0,0],
    ]
};
```

My code at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vloryan/njhzzvhq/).

Answer (score 1):

To format the y-axis labels, you can use labelInterpolationFnc in axisY. To create the labels you need, you can add the following function to 'axisY' in 'options':

```
labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        return 'X'
    }
    return String.fromCharCode(64 + value)
}
```

My code at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07tha7q5/).